# No .gitignore isto '!/wp-content/plugins/' é igual a isto '!/wp-content/plugins/*'?

Tags: git

No .gitignore esta notação

```
!/wp-content/plugins/
```

possui o mesmo resultado que esta outra?

```
!/wp-content/plugins/*
```